# Pentaho Kettle Error in Archive Files - org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: File closed

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

I have a job which is set to archive files in a directory.

It looks like it is running into the error `org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: File closed` when it attempts to create the zip file. However, the zip file *does* get created, and the files *are* added to it.

I've sent the package to a colleague of mine and he was able to run it on his machine without issues. He has the same Java & Kettle versions as I do.

> Java: Version 8 Update 45
>
> Kettle Build: 5.3.0.0-213

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

```
Starting job entry
The Zip file [C:\yadayada\Data\Unprocessed\WipBeforeExec_99991231_000000.zip] already exists !
Folder [file:///C:/yadayada/Data/Unprocessed] exists.
New Zip file to create [C:\yadayada\Data\Unprocessed\WipBeforeExec_99991231_000000_20151105_092631981.zipNew Zip file to create [
Found 1file(s) in the directory [C:\yadayada\Data\WIP]
Adding file [file:///C:/yadayada/Data/WIP/20150506101358-PickShip-449380.xml] from directory [C:\yadayada\Data\WIP]
ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : Could not create file [C:\yadayada\Data\Unprocessed\WipBeforeExec_99991231_000000_20151105_092631981.zip] , exception:
ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: File closed.
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.util.MonitorOutputStream.assertOpen(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.util.MonitorOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.zipfile.JobEntryZipFile.processRowFile(JobEntryZipFile.java:627)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.zipfile.JobEntryZipFile.execute(JobEntryZipFile.java:968)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:716)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:859)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:859)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:859)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:532)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:424)
ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : Error closing zip file entry for file 'file:///C:/yadayada/Data/WIP'
ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: File closed.
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.util.MonitorOutputStream.assertOpen(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.util.MonitorOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.zipfile.JobEntryZipFile.processRowFile(JobEntryZipFile.java:729)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.zipfile.JobEntryZipFile.execute(JobEntryZipFile.java:968)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:716)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:859)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:859)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:859)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:532)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:424)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've "fixed" this problem by downgrading to Java 7 Update 76.

I had found the following links on the pentaho site which helped hint that downgrading the version may help.

http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-12270

http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-13413

My only hypothesis as to the root of the problem is that, *if I remember correctly*, things were originally working on my computer until I had installed some windows updates for some SharePoint 2013 PowerShell management features.